# issue reading from CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter with Selenium Webdriver sampler & JAVA. 
I have a CSV file with username and password. My test has CSV Data Set Config to read the file and Webdriver sampler. I am writing selenium code in java. 
I wants to read username and password from CSV file and use it in my selenium script. Here is my code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt41u.png)
[CSV Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCHc9.png)

```
import openqa.selenium.OutputType.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();

var ctx = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext();
var vars = ctx.getVariables();

String userName = WDS.args[0]; -- the result of this line is "loginName" instead of actual log in name. same for 2nd line. 
//String userName = vars.get('loginName');
```

The issue i have is its not picking from CSV. The above two lines produce result "loginName" instead of picking actual login name from the file. I have used single quote, double quote etc, but no luck. Using ${loginName} gives error. Any Idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove these 2 lines from your script as they are not required, moreover they will cause syntax errors given you use `java` as the language

   ```
   var ctx = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext();
   var vars = ctx.getVariables();
   ```
2. Choose `groovy` from the Language dropdown. When you pick `java` it is not the "real" java, it is rather [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter so if you want to use normal Java syntax - choose Groovy. Moreover [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for all forms of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). This is due to the fact that [Groovy has much better performance than other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Evidence that Groovy script works:

[image: JMeter WebDriver Variables]

Comment: No this does not work. My Selenium script is in java and I want to use Java not any other language. If i pick Groovy from the language drop down then i get errors.

Comment: "this does not work" is very informative, here everyone is telepathic and can immediately guess what is your problem by reading this stanza. You have the evidence that the suggested approach works.